# CDI: @Inject, qualifiers, @Produces, differen implementation

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I would like to have CD @Produces method that based on some condition is producing suitable implementation of ZipCodeChecker implementation. It is properly instantiated implementation of CountryZipCodeChecker which is used by CountryZipCodeValidator to validate zip code suitable to address set in Address entity. I have made something like this:

```
   public class CountryZipCodeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CountryZipCode, Address> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CountryZipCodeValidator.class.getName());

    @Inject
    private Instance<ZipCodeChecker> checkerInstance;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CountryZipCode constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Address value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Validating zip code format for typed country.");

        if(value.getZipCode() == null || value.getCountry() == null)
            return true;

        // selecting ZipCodeChecker instance specific to country name set in Address object
        ZipCodeChecker checker = checkerInstance.select(new CountryQualifierLiteral(value.getCountry())).get();

        return checker.isFormatValid(value.getZipCode());
     }
   }
```

and **ZipCodeCheckerFactory** which **@Produces** suitable **ZipCodeChecker**

```
    public class ZipCodeCheckerFactory {

    @Inject
    CountryZipCodeChecker countryZipCodeChecker;

    @Produces
    public ZipCodeChecker createZipCodeChecker(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {

        // retrieving country name from injection point to return country specific checker instance
        Country countryQualifier = injectionPoint.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(Country.class);
        String countryName = countryQualifier.value();

        countryZipCodeChecker.setCountryName(countryName);

        return countryZipCodeChecker;
    }

}
```

here is snippet of **CountryZipCodeChecker**:

```
public class CountryZipCodeChecker implements ZipCodeChecker { /*...*/}
```

here is ZipCodeChecker interface:

```
    public interface ZipCodeChecker {

    public boolean isFormatValid(String zipCode);
}
```

and qualifier implementation:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER,})
public @interface Country {

    @Nonbinding String value() default "United States";
}
```

and I get such an error and NullPointer exception when trying to call on @Injected zipCodeChecker.isValid() method:

```
 org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.ArquillianProxyException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException : WELD-001302: Duplicate qualifiers:  [@pl.salonea.qualifiers.Country(value=United States)] [Proxied because : Original exception not deserilizable, ClassNotFoundException]
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.checkQualifier(ResolvableBuilder.java:210)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifier(ResolvableBuilder.java:177)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifiers(ResolvableBuilder.java:200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your use case, you really dont need a producer here.  You need to use the instance injection:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, TYPE, PARAMETER})
public @interface ZipCodeCheck {

   //The country which this zipcodecher can validate
   Country value();
}

public class ZipCodeCheckImpl extends AnnotationLiteral<ZipCodeCheck> implements ZipCodeCheck {
   private final Country country;

   public ZipCodeCheckImpl(final Country country) {
     this.country = country;
   }

   public Country value() {
     return country;
   }
}

public interface ZipCoderChecker {

   boolean isValid(final String zipcode);
}
```

Two implementation

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ZipCodeCheck(USA)
public class USZipCodeChecker implements ZipCoderChecker {
}


@ApplicationScoped
@ZipCodeCheck(GB)
public class GBZipCodeChecker implements ZipCoderChecker {
}
```

Usage:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class CounryZipCodeValidator {

  @Any
  @Inject
  private Instance<ZipCodeChecker> zipCodeCheckers;

  public void validate(final Address address) {
    Country country = address.getCountry();
    ZipCodeChecker zipCodeChecker = zipCodeCheckers.select(new ZipCodeCheckImpl(country)).get(); //will return null if no zipcoderchecker for the country.
    checkState(zipCodeChecker.isValid(address.getZipCode()), "Invalid zipcode");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok... 1. Maybe producer no need to use but I would like too know where there was an error and why it doesn't work correctly... 2. your approach don't differ a too much... 3. your solution have a problem cause Zip code formats is about 100?